# AudioInputStream for AudioPreProcessor

Tags: java, android, inputstream, audioinputstream

I'm working with comirva library and trying to implement *getAudioPreProcessor* method that takes the file and gets the InputStream. The problem is that Android doesn't support AudioSystem nor AudioInputStream. There is a class implemented in comirva ***AudioPreProcessor*** (constructor: AudioPreProcessor(AudioInputStream in) ), which I need. How can I implement a method to send AudioInputStream type in Android? 
Hope my question is clear. Thanks.